# Range checking for my remove function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, range

So I have a method in c++ that takes an array and removes a certain number of values in the array. The method removes the range of values from the starting value all the way up to but not including the end value. `void dynamic_array::remove(int start, int end) {`

The only problem I'm having is with the range checking. So I've set up a way to check to make sure the start and end values are not in the incorrect places however whenever I test the code, it appears that it doesn't catch the range exception. Here's the code that's supposed to check the exception:

```
if (not (0 <= ((start <= (end < size))))){
        throw exception(SUBSCRIPT_RANGE_EXCEPTION);
    }
```

Comment: `if (start<0 || end<start || end>=size)`?

Comment: What I don't quite understand is that this is such an elementary, newbie mistake (and I mean, newbie), yet you've moved onto more advanced topics such as writing classes, using exception handling, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ does not work this way. The result of a single logical comparison is a boolean value. For example, the first comparison:

```
end < size
```

If this comparison is true, the result becomes a true value, which is for all practical purposes is 1. So, your expression now becomes, for all practical purposes:

```
if (not (0 <= ((start <= 1)))){
```

Which is already pretty much nonsensical, not to mention that there isn't a `not` operator in C++. Things pretty much roll downhill, from that point on.

You just need to make two logical comparisons: start < end, and end <= size. If you spend a few moments to think about it, you would realize this is all you need:

```
if (!(start < end && end <= size))
```

Comment: There is a `not` operator in C++, but nobody uses it

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use the notation `1 < x < 2` in c++  (or most languages). So you have to do each comparison separately. ie. `(1<x) && (x<2)` (brackets not really necessary here).

If you are interested, you actually can use the notation, but it means something different than you might think. It means that you first compare `1<x` which gives either true (1) or zero(0) and then you compare this 1 or 0 with two.

Answer (score 1):

It should be written

```
if(!(0 <= start && start <= end && end < size)){
    throw exception
}
```

As i know, C++ can't understand the way you write it.

Comment: Too many parentheses. `if(!(0 <= start && start <= end && end < size))` is sufficient.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to delete that. <g> The comment by Mooing Duck to the question puts it much better, going gone step further by applying DeMorgan's theorem to get rid of the negation.